# Links inserted in Civimail are not redirecting and require a log-in

Tags: civimail, joomla

This seems to have started with CiviCRM 5.27.0 on a Joomla installation.  When using Civimail to send out an e-mail to our users, the link no longer redirects to the initial destination but goes to the Joomla Administrator log-in page. If you are logged in as an administrator, then the link works properly on the redirect. I've upgraded to 5.27.2 with the same result.

Comment: Maybe related: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1865?

Comment: Not exactly. From what I can tell,’it is inserting /administrator/ to the URL. Not sure why this behavior started recently as I do not believe it’s had that in the url before.

Comment: Ok, just I was thinking the original change it leads to (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17312) was for 5.27.0 and has a comment at the bottom about "did not test on joomla", and is in general about changing mail urls. So maybe not exactly like the ticket but might be related somehow. I'm not really familiar with joomla so maybe if you post a comment in that ticket someone there might know if it's related.

Comment: I know that on wordpress sites sometimes security plugins such as wordfence can get in the middle of any requests like that, might be worth checking if you installed anything similar on Joomla and its kicking out the traffic as a possible intrusion on the site?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. It has been resolved by https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17760